# How to apply search criteria for CJuiDatePicker field in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to filter grid data using CJUIDatePicker search field, How to put search criteria for date,

I displayed Grid Date column value like "dd/mm/yyyy"

My DB storage format is "yyyy-mm-dd h:mi:ss"

Please provide solution to this,

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode date you get from the user in model as

```
$this->date, explode this
```

Write another function in model

```
$variable = explode(",",$this->date)
$this->date = $variable[2].$variable[1].$variable[0];
```

now the date will be fine so your search results will go good